# Which is the lightest window manager in your opinion?

Tags: window-manager

Which WM worked best for you guys considering the performance?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of how this is worded, although it's not opinionated this question does ask a lot.  It might be better if you asked for light window managers instead of expecting people to research every single window manager ever created for you.

Comment: Yes I could have asked for light window managers, but what I need to know which is the lightest one. Someone must know which one it is.

Comment: Since we are talking about the worlds largest open source and do it yourself community there are theoretically an infinite number of window managers, do you only care about popular ones or do you want someone to study 100% of the internet to find your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like that. I just want to know a windows manger that's quite light if not the lightest. I have already considered icewm, openbox, fvwm etc.

Comment: The lightest WM and there is not lighter. That would be no WM.you don't need a WM.  And at zero features, zero bytes, and zero processes. No WM is good value for money.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the lightest X11 window manager (I know your question didn’t specify X11, so that’s an assumption) is one of

- [9wm](https://github.com/9wm/9wm)
- [lwm](http://www.jfc.org.uk/software/lwm.html) (based on 9wm)
- [wm2](https://www.all-day-breakfast.com/wm2/)

All of these are less than 100KiB in size on disk and use less than half a megabyte of memory.

[twm](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/twm), the standard X11 window manager since X11R4, is also quite light (less than 200KiB on disk).

Comment: or try the `xwm` window manager, it is super tiny.

Comment: @KJ7LNW are you referring to [this `xwm`](https://github.com/mcpcpc/xwm)?

Comment: Yep.  Or [sdorfehs](https://github.com/jcs/sdorfehs) ("starfish") is good too.  At least for the insane who think their X install should _act like a terminal_.  Personally I use compiz and mate.  Some might consider [xmonad](https://xmonad.org/) to be thin in terms of performance, but it has quite a few install-time dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this qualifies but the lightest WM is no WM:

> xinit is typically used to start window managers or desktop environments. While you can also use xinit to run GUI applications without a window manager, many graphical applications expect an EWMH compliant window manager. Display managers start Xorg for you and generally source xprofile.

([from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit))